# T-SQL OPENJSON Read a JSON string with double quotes in a field

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql

I have a JSON `NVARCHAR` of an array of objects.  Within an object is a field that has double quotes in the value. `OPENJSON` will read the file up until the object that contains a field with the double quotes in the value. I have tried parsing and converting the string and everything else I could find on the Internet.  When I copy the content of the `NVARCHAR(MAX)` variable into Notepad and copy the data back into a `NVARCHAR(MAX)` variable the `OPENJSON` processes the entire file.  I though some UTC-8 or some other conversion  might work but I have hit a wall and would like to understand why a copy into notepad works.

```
SELECT * 
FROM OPENJSON(@InJson);
```

This does not work:

> JSON text is not properly formatted. Unexpected character '"' is found at position 45048

Copy [Ctrl]+C into notepad and [Ctrl]+V into the variable below and it processes.

```
DECLARE @TestJson NVARCHAR(MAX); 

SET @TestJson = '' SELECT ISJSON(@TestJson)
```

The `ISJSON` returns false for the `@InJson` and a True for the `@TestJson`

What is happening here?

```
** UPDATE -  I don't  know how to add a separate entry to this string with the EDIT button or how to copy SQL code into this edit area.
```

I was trying to find the best way to get a Curl output of a JSON file from Algolia into a SQL table.  I was storing the results into a table of VARCHAR(MAX).

```
~~~
DECLARE @CmdResult TABLE
(
    Id INT IDENTITY(1, 1),
    Line NVARCHAR(512) NULL
);
INSERT INTO @CmdResult
(
   Line
)
EXEC @CmdShellResult = xp_cmdshell @CurlCommand;
~~~~
```

Then I had to parse the lines back into a single string for processing.  This is a BAD approach and was the source of my problem.  Somewhere the unreadable characters were getting set.  I have since changed the process to store the result into a file.  Then read the file and parse.  This works FINE.

```
~~~~
SET @CurlCommand = 'curl -o "C:\Temp\GeoTest.json" ' + @CurlCommand + ' ' + @URL;
EXEC @CmdShellResult = xp_cmdshell @CurlCommand;
DECLARE @InJson VARCHAR(MAX);
SELECT @InJson=BulkColumn
FROM   OPENROWSET(BULK'C:\Temp\GeoTest.json',SINGLE_BLOB) x;
~~~
```

The JSON file has transactional header and footer information that needs to be parsed and removed to get to the real data.  The goal was to get the CURL command into a single variable so that string modifications could be done and then use OPENJSON(@InJSson) to process the data.  I could NOT find a path to get the data directly into a VARCHAR variable without using the output to a file from the Curl command.  If there is a direct path to a variable that would be less overhead, please provide a comment.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question as text, no images.

Comment: Presumably there is some hidden Unicode character. Please copy/paste the relevant JSON into your question **EXACTLY** directly from SSMS, do not paste it into anything else first.

Comment: DECLARE (asterisk)TestJson NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET (asterisk)TestJson = '[{“name”:”value”,“title”: “value without a double quote in it”,“anotherField”: “another value”},{“name”:”value”,“title”: “value “with” a double quote in it”,“anotherField”: “another value”}]'
SELECT ISJSON((asterisk)TestJson)

SELECT [key], [value], [type] FROM OPENJSON((asterisk)TestJson)   The asterisk is a reserved character in these comments to tag a person.  Please substitute the words above with an actual asterisk or at sign.

Comment: I would have preferred if you would put that directly into your post using the [edit] button. From what I can see, the quotes are smart quotes `“` and `”` not normal double quotes `"` so not surprising it's erroring. Also the value with a quote in it should have that quote escaped like this `\"` and if you do all this then it works. See https://dbfiddle.uk/lzxVs1o6 Clearly whatever generates your JSON is broken. Are you sure you copied this **DIRECTLY** from SSMS and didn't go via a word processor?

Comment: the json which causing issue - would be nice to see it here.